# Sanitize multi dimensional array in php

Tags: php

Wrote this function to clean up array and LEAVE 0, null & false as valid values.

```
function sanitize_array($array = array()) {
    if (is_array($array)) {
        $filtered_array = array_filter($array, create_function('$a', 'return trim($a)!=="";'));
        $filtered_and_trimmed_array = array();
        foreach ($filtered_array as $k => $v) {
            if (!is_array($v) && !is_object($v)) {
                $filtered_and_trimmed_array[$k] = htmlspecialchars(trim($v));
            }
            if (is_array($v)) {
                $filtered_and_trimmed_array[$k] = $this->sanitize_array($v);
            }
        }
        return $filtered_and_trimmed_array;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

It's giving me the following error:

> g: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/imgimportsinc/public_html/img_scripts_library/img_functions.php(328) : runtime-created function on line 1
>
> Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in /home/imgimportsinc/public_html/img_scripts_library/img_functions.php(328) : runtime-created function on line 1

Comment: error log is clear enough.. `trim()` is expecting a string not an array.

Comment: btw, who use `create_function` anymore? just do that with a closure

Comment: On your is_array true, you try to recurse  $v.....

Comment: Side note: `trim(0)!==""` is `True`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to check that the value to be evaluated is a string before trimming it.

```
$filtered_array = array_filter($array, function($v) {
    return !is_string($v) || (is_string($v) && trim($v) !== "");
});
```